# AZUREDEVOPS - API -401 - Authentication error

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm receiving the 401 response when I'm following these docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/memberentitlementmanagement/members/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/subject-query/query?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

I'm able to create projects, list groups, users, etc.
Could you please help me understand what is happening in this case?

My permissions are:
Graph: Read & Manage
Identity: Read & Manage
Member Entitlement Management: Read & Write
Project and Team: Read, Write & Manage
Tokens: Read & Manage

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I'm executing this: https://vsaex.dev.azure.com//{organization}/_apis/GroupEntitlements/{groupId}/members/{memberId}?api-version=6.1-preview.1 on postman

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the steps below to troubleshooting.

1. Select `all the scopes` via `Custom defined`(not the `Full access` option) when creating the PAT.
2. Test to call the API you want, if it succeeds, it means the scopes for the previous PAT is not enough, you could slowly increase scopes. If all the scopes don't work, this doc as below should be the reason.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-pats-with-policies-for-administrators?view=azure-devops#restrict-creation-of-full-scoped-pats

[image]